# How would one solve the following polynomial equation by hand?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, contest-math

$2z^6+3z^5+20z^4+27z^3+20z^2+3z+2=0.$

We are given as a hint that there are no multiple roots, no rational roots, and no complex roots having rational real and imaginary parts.

Source: 2006 Konhauser Problemfest.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Is it a current contest?  How does asking MSE count as "by hand"?

Comment: Sorry, I just added the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the polynomial is symmetric. By this I mean that the coefficient of $z^6$ is the same as the coefficient of $z^0$, the coefficient of $z^5$ is the same as the coefficient of $z^1$, etc. Now what we can do is divide both sides by $z^3$ so we get $$2z^3+3z^2+20z+27+\frac{20}{z}+\frac{3}{z^2}+\frac{2}{z^3}=0$$
$$\implies 2\left(z^3+\frac{1}{z^3}\right)+3\left(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)+20\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)+27=0$$
If we set $a=z+\frac{1}{z}$, we have
$$a^2=z^2+2+\frac{1}{z^2}\implies z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}=a^2-2$$
Similarly
$$z^3+\frac{1}{z^3}=\left(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)-\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)=(a^2-2)(a)-a=a^3-3a$$
Now plug this back into the equation to get $2(a^3-3a)+3(a^2-2)+20a+27=0$. After expanding, we get
$$2a^3+3a^2+14a+21=0$$
There's a factorization that you need to see (and it's what makes the problem solvable). With this factorization you can solve for a and then solve for $z$. Hope this helps and if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method that I really like: (P.S., the reason why it works is because the symmetry in the coefficients).

Define $P_i(x) = x^i+x^{-i}.$ Divide both side by $z^3$ because you know it cannot be $0$. You would end up with

$$2P_3+3P_2+20P_1+27=0$$

Now try to express $P_2$ and $P_3$ in terms of $P_1$, e.g., $P_2=P_1^2-2$. eventually you will have something as a cubic in $P_1$, treat $P_1$ as an  unknown you see $$(2P_1+3)(P_1^2+7)=0$$

the rest is simple for you i beleieve.